# Error: "Cannot send headers", when fetching table data (direct SQL query)

Tags: magento-1.7, database

I want to get a variable from a table of another module.
 I followed this tutorial: https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');

$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

var_dump($results);
```

and it works great for `catalog/product` table.
Then I tried to do the same thing for the custom table from a module: 
 `$query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('amtable/rate');`
 I concluded that the "table name" should be `amtable/rate` by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138637/7563153) comment and looking at the `config.xml`:
 `<global>
        <models>
            <amtable>
                <class>Amasty_Table_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>amtable_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </amtable>
            <amtable_mysql4>
                <class>Amasty_Table_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <method>
                        <table>am_table_method</table>
                    </method>
                    <method_store>
                        <table>am_table_method_store</table>
                    </method_store>
                    <rate>
                        <table>am_table_rate</table>
                    </rate>
                </entities>
            </amtable_mysql4>`


But I get an error: 
 `Cannot send headers; headers already sent in app/code/local/Jurgis/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php, line 15` 
Line 15 is: `var_dump($results);`
 What could I be doing wrong or is there something I'm missing? 
 P.S. sorry about the formatting, couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: yes, 
var_dump($results); is create s issue.It is try to reset header.Best way to use log

Comment: How do I print out an array like that using a `log`?

Comment: print_r($var, true) will return the array as a string representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what was causing it, but it was fixed by adding `exit();` after `var_dump($results);`
 Hope this helps someone.